# foreach loop wont generate unique list item id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, foreach

I try to develop a comment system. The foreach row $result contains variables from a database named posts. For the comment, function is the popup. The id of the post that is AUTO_INCREMENT, the author of the post and the comment become submitted to a file that insert the three values into a database named comments. The second foreach loop, $comments, should show the comments when the user click the popup button. That don't works because the id `<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?>" type="text" />` isn't unique and the comments of every single list item become not right showed, but the posts have unique ids. All comments become showed. How can I change it that the id is in every newly created list item unique?

```
<div data-role="content">
    <?php include( "list.php"); ?>
    <div data-demo-html="true">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">

            <?php foreach ($result as $key=> $row): ?>

            <li id="listone" name="listone" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b ui-li-has-count ui-first-child">
                <?php echo $row[ 'date']; ?>
            </li>
            <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a">
                <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                    <div class="ui-btn-text">
                        <a class="ui-link-inherit">
                            <p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong></strong>
                                <?php echo $row[ 'time']; ?>
                            </p>
                            <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['title']; ?></strong>
                            </p>
                            <p class="ui-li-desc">
                                <?php echo $row[ 'text']; ?>
                            </p>

                            <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['town']; ?></strong>
                            </p>
                            <a href="#popupcomment" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">comment</a>
                            <div data-role="popup" id="popupcomment" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
                                <form data-ajax="false" name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./comments.php" method="post" style="padding:20px 40px;">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <?php include( "showcomments.php"); ?>
                                        <?php foreach ($comments as $keyComment=> $rowComment): ?>
                                        <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $rowComment['username']; ?></strong>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="ui-li-desc">
                                            <?php echo $rowComment[ 'comment']; ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="text" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="autorpost" id="autorpost" value="<?php echo $row['autor']; ?>" type="text" />
                                        <!-- autor des posts -->
                                        <textarea rows="1" name="text" id="text" class="foo"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="footer">
                                        <input type="submit" name="save" value="comment" class="button" data-theme="a" />
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                        </a>
            </li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- div content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

> showcomments.php:

```
    $hostname='localhost';
        $user='root';
        $password='';

$id = $row['id'];
try {
                        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=searchfood",$user,$password);

                        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                         $sql = "SELECT id, username, comment, time 
FROM comments 
WHERE  id_post = $id 
ORDER BY id DESC"; // oder (longitude between $loo and $lo or latitude  between $laa and $la) versuchen
  if ($com = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
      // then after fetchColumn
     $comments = $com->fetchAll();       
   }                        
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }
```

> comments.php:

```
    $hostname='localhost';
        $user='root';
        $password='';

if(isset($_POST["id"])){                    
                try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=searchfood", $user, $password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
        // prepare your query
        $query = 'INSERT INTO comments (username, autorpost, comment, id_post, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, now())';

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        // bind variables
        $stmt->execute(array($_COOKIE['username'], $_POST['autorpost'], $_POST['text'], $_POST['id']));
        // pull last insert id
        $new = $dbh->lastInsertId(); 

        // show success message or redirect, whatever you want
        echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
        $message['success'] = 'Neuer Benutzer (' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']) . ') wurde angelegt, <a href="login.php">weiter zur Anmeldung</a>.';
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lendsth/main.php", true, 302);

    }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }

    }
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you want to do, but to show only one comment when clickng the poppup button, you should to use : <?php echo **$rowComment['id']**; ?> instead of <?php echo $row['id']; ?>

Comment: Your code would be easier to understand, if you included the relevant code from showcomments.php.

Comment: why don't you use the `$key` to generate unique id. It will be numbers starting from `0` if you are not using special `key` inside your `$result` array.

Comment: I add the relevant files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

Create a variable called `$i;`

And iterate it each time then add to the **id**.

```
<div data-role="content">
    <?php include( "list.php"); ?>
    <div data-demo-html="true">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($result as $key=> $row): ?>
            <li id="listone" name="listone" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b ui-li-has-count ui-first-child"> <?php echo $row[ 'date']; ?> </li>
            <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a">
                <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a class="ui-link-inherit">
                <p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong></strong> <?php echo $row[ 'time']; ?> </p>
                <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['title']; ?></strong> </p>
                <p class="ui-li-desc"> <?php echo $row[ 'text']; ?> </p>
                <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['town']; ?></strong> </p>
                <a href="#popupcomment" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">comment</a>
                <div data-role="popup" id="popupcomment" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
                    <form data-ajax="false" name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./comments.php" method="post" style="padding:20px 40px;">
                        <div class="content">
                            <?php include( "showcomments.php"); ?>
                            <?php foreach ($comments as $keyComment=> $rowComment): ?>
                            <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $rowComment['username']; ?></strong> </p>
                            <p class="ui-li-desc"> <?php echo $rowComment[ 'comment']; ?> </p>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="text" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="autorpost" id="autorpost" value="<?php echo $row['autor']; ?>" type="text" />
                            <!-- autor des posts -->
                            <textarea rows="1" name="text" id="text" class="foo"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                            <input type="submit" name="save" value="comment" class="button" data-theme="a" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </a> </li>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- div content -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention but that wont help :(

Comment: @Bodoppels do you have a live version of this?